# Неправильный перенос части String на новую строку

Tags: java, строки

Здравствуйте. Нужно создать файл конфигурации с расширением ini. Задаю этот файл таким кодом:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+UID+".ini");
```

Где UID - определенный код, переданный клиентом. В итоге получается примерно следующее:

```
C:\Users\тутимяпользователя\workspace\Encryptcserver\345161тутимяпользователяKHtGuI

.ini
```

Получается, что адрес на одной строке, а расширение - уже на другой. В итоге компилятор ругается и выдает такое:

> java.io.IOException: Синтаксическая
> ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или
> метке тома

Подскажите решение, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Ну... Может, у вас в конце UID символ переноса строки (/n) стоит?

Comment: Нет. Самое интересное, что на Unix системах все работает нормально. Как я понял, адрес слишком длинный. Когда всего 1 директория, например, C:/UID/, то все работает. Видимо, адрес слишком длинный.

Comment: @TheCoolKuid на Unix системах несколько другой символ переноса строки. Проверьте еще раз свой UID, возможно, @ЮрийСПб прав.

Answer (score 1):

У меня возникала такая же ошибка. Это происходит из-за того, что в имени файла/папки содержатся запрещённые символы. Например, двоеточие быть не может, имя файла `COM1` тоже быть не может, и т.д. Попробуй сначала в этой папке сам создать файл с названием, которое хочет программа, и увидишь, какой символ запрёщен.